# Webix Calendar plugin disables scroll and swipe on android

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, webix

I am developing a mobile app using phonegap and i need to use a calendar plugin. I found out this awesome one but it disables my scroll and swipe events. I though it was a problem in the order i was calling the javascript files but I tried to move it around with no luck.

this is the addon: http://webix.com/demo/calendar/fullscreen/

**My initialization is as follow:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**index.js:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        app.initialize();
    });

    var app = {

            initialize: function() {
                this.bindEvents()
            },

            bindEvents: function() {
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false)
                $(document).on("pageshow", app.onDeviceReady);              
            },

            onDeviceReady: function() {
                app.receivedEvent('deviceready')
            },

            receivedEvent: function(id){

                    webix.ui({
                        view:"window",
                        height:350,
                        width:$(window).width(),
                        left:0, top:40,
                        move:true,
                        head:"Calendar",
                        body:{
                            weekHeader:true,
                            view:"calendar",
                            events:webix.Date.isHoliday,
                            width:0,
                            height:0,
                            monthSelect:false
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
});
```

Now if I have have something large enough to trigger an overflow it will let me scroll up and down but as soon as I insert `<script type="text/javascript" src="webix.js"></script>` the scroll stops working. Same for swipes.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the next line after loading Webix library on the page

```
webix.Touch.disable();
```

it will prevent any alterations of touch and scroll handling.